# Get data from different table and column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a basic "blog" where different people with different user avatars are able to post content. I have 3 tables in MySQL, users, posts and following.

What I am trying to do is to display the avatar of the user who posted the post. And I can't get this to work, I have the code I've been working on below. It's little bit longer but it's mostly echo results in the end, I didn't include these in my example since the code got big. What is the correct way to get whoever posted what's avatar since it's in two different tables? I tried messing around with mysqli_multi_query earlier with no luck.

```
        include "connect.php";
        $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts
        WHERE user_id = $user_id OR (user_id IN (SELECT user2_id FROM following WHERE user1_id='$user_id')) 
        AND (SELECT user_img FROM users where user_img='$user_img')
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $postid = $row['id'];
            $post = $row['post'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
            $user_img = $row['user_img'];
            $type = -1;
            }
```

Comment: Can you please post the table structures too? And please try to run your SQL query in MySQL Workbench as that might help you focus your answer. Also, please read up on using JOINs, they will help you, a lot. Also, is this related to a homework assignment?

Comment: @Nabheet I read about JOINs and did an experiment, I used this     SELECT posts.*, users.user_img FROM posts AS posts INNER JOIN users as users ON (users.user_img=users.user_img)

Seems like it duplicates the result by 2, 3 or 4. So basically it shows the same thing many times. It's also project related to school, so it's a project.

Comment: Not sure if it was a typo but your JOIN clause is joining on the same table - the syntax is tableA.columnA = tableB.columnB. And look up how to remove duplicates in SQL query result. You have made great progress! Good luck!